# Filtrar LonglistSelector [CATEGORIAS]

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xaml

Olá, eu tenho um webservice que me retorna uma lista de "categorias" com suas sub-categorias .

Necessito de ajuda para fazer a "filtragem disto", por exemplo:

Categoria 1 tem as sub-categoria 1 e 2;

Categoria 2 tem a sub-categoria 3;

Categoria 3 tem a sub-categoria 4, 5 e 6;

Quero que ao selecionar a categoria 1, venha na próxima tela as sub-categorias 1 e 2.

O meu web-service, já retorna para mim todas as categorias e sub-categorias de cada uma, quero saber como manusear elas para operar dessa maneira..

O parse feito para pegar os códigos de categoria, seriam estas e são adicionadas à um ObservableCollection:

```
string strDataTable = e.Result;

        try
        {
            if (strDataTable.Length < 20)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não há dados disponíveis no momento, tente novamente mais tarde.\nCaso o erro persista, contactar o suporte técnico.");
                return;
            }
            XElement doc = XElement.Parse(strDataTable);

            foreach (XElement row in doc.Elements("GWDataTable"))
            {
                Produtos produto = new Produtos();

                produto.descCateg = row.Element("DESCRICAOCATEGORIA").Value.ToString();
                produto.descFamil = row.Element("DESCRICAOFAMILIA").Value.ToString();
                produto.descGrupo = row.Element("DESCRICAOGRUPO").Value.ToString();
                produto.descReceita = row.Element("DESCRICAOCRECEITA").Value.ToString();
                produto.descricao = row.Element("OBS").Value.ToString();
                produto.produto = row.Element("DESCRICAOPROD").Value.ToString();
                produto.unidade = row.Element("UNIDADE").Value.ToString();
                produto.precoN = row.Element("PRECONORMAL").Value.ToString();
                produto.precoP = row.Element("PRECOPROMOCIONAL").Value.ToString();

                produto.codCategoria = row.Element("CODCATEGORIA").Value.ToString();
                produto.codFamilia = row.Element("CODFAMILIA").Value.ToString();
                produto.codGrupo = row.Element("CODGRUPO").Value.ToString();
                produto.codReceita = row.Element("CODCRECEITA").Value.ToString();




                Resultados.ResProdutos.Add(produto);
            }
            try
            {
                SelectorProdutos.ItemsSource = Resultados.ResProdutos;
                SetProgressIndicator(false);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERRO");
            }

        }


Resultados.ResProdutos.Add(produto);}
```

Produtos:

```
public class Produtos
{
    public string descReceita { get; set; }
    public string descGrupo { get; set; }
    public string descCateg { get; set; }
    public string descFamil { get; set; }



    public string produto { get; set; }
    public string codReceita { get; set; }
    public string codGrupo { get; set; }
    public string codCategoria { get; set; }
    public string codFamilia { get; set; }
    public string precoN { get; set; }
    public string precoP { get; set; }
    public string unidade { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }

}
}
```

Prefiro usar um SelectionChanged para começar a partir do usuário clicando no item do LongListSelector, passar para a próxima tela, com a próxima categoria:

```
private void SelectorProdutos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (SelectorProdutos.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Telas/frm5Grupo.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro");
        }
    }
```

De primeira eu envio para a tela o CODRECEITA para o meu LongListSelector, para o usuário selecionar o item que deseja, mas após ser selecionado, como posso prosseguir a filtragem?

Código XML de resposta do webservice:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<NewDataSet>
 <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
 <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="GWDataTable" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
 <xs:complexType>
 <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
 <xs:element name="GWDataTable">
 <xs:complexType> 
 <xs:sequence> 
 <xs:element name="CODPROD" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="DESCRICAOPROD" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="CODCRECEITA" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="DESCRICAOCRECEITA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="CODGRUPO" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="DESCRICAOGRUPO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="CODCATEGORIA" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="DESCRICAOCATEGORIA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="CODFAMILIA" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="DESCRICAOFAMILIA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="PRECONORMAL" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="PRECOPROMOCIONAL" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="UNIDADE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
 <xs:element name="OBS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
 </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:choice>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
 <GWDataTable>
 <CODPROD>1</CODPROD>
 <DESCRICAOPROD>CERVEJA ANTARCTICA</DESCRICAOPROD>
 <CODCRECEITA>12</CODCRECEITA>
 <DESCRICAOCRECEITA>BEBIDAS</DESCRICAOCRECEITA>
 <CODGRUPO>15</CODGRUPO>
 <DESCRICAOGRUPO>BEBIBAS ALCOOLICA</DESCRICAOGRUPO>
 <CODCATEGORIA>200</CODCATEGORIA>
 <DESCRICAOCATEGORIA>EM LATA</DESCRICAOCATEGORIA>
 <CODFAMILIA>105</CODFAMILIA>
 <DESCRICAOFAMILIA>CERVEJA</DESCRICAOFAMILIA>
 <PRECONORMAL>2.6</PRECONORMAL>
 <PRECOPROMOCIONAL>2.3</PRECOPROMOCIONAL>
 <UNIDADE>LATA</UNIDADE>
 <OBS>Quantidade máxima por cliente (5).</OBS>
 </GWDataTable>
 <GWDataTable>
 <CODPROD>14</CODPROD>
 <DESCRICAOPROD>AMACIANTE OMO</DESCRICAOPROD>
 <CODCRECEITA>19</CODCRECEITA> 
 <DESCRICAOCRECEITA>LIMPEZA</DESCRICAOCRECEITA> 
 <CODGRUPO>121</CODGRUPO>
 <DESCRICAOGRUPO>LAVA ROUPAS</DESCRICAOGRUPO>
 <CODCATEGORIA>76</CODCATEGORIA>
 <DESCRICAOCATEGORIA>EM PÓ</DESCRICAOCATEGORIA>
 <CODFAMILIA>15</CODFAMILIA> 
 <DESCRICAOFAMILIA>AMACIANTES</DESCRICAOFAMILIA>
 <PRECONORMAL>7.4</PRECONORMAL>
 <PRECOPROMOCIONAL>6.99</PRECOPROMOCIONAL> 
 <UNIDADE>CX</UNIDADE>
 <OBS>Validade da oferta 15/05.</OBS>
 </GWDataTable>
 </NewDataSet>
 </string>
```

Comment: Você tem uma dúvida técnica ou uma dúvida de processo? Nós daqui não conhecemos sua tela e normalmente os posts aqui são sobre dúvidas técnicas. Nós não podemos ajudar apenas lendo cat 1,2,3... e o que você deseja fazer. Se existe um problema técnico de uso de tecnologia, coloque mais informações na questão e seja mais específico. Você fala de Webservice e de Tela ambos não foram mostrados.

Comment: @Malkaviano Você pode rever-lo agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi é uma questão de processo, você vai usar essa seleção da categoria e puxar de novo os dados do WebService apenas as subcategorias da categoria selecionada. No 
`navigate` passe a categoria como parâmetro para fazer a query na nova página que você mandou abrir e mostrar as subcategorias. Se você não souber como, coloque mais informações sobre as chamadas do WebService que nós ajudamos.

Exemplo:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Telas/frm5Grupo.xaml?categoria=1", UriKind.Relative));
```

Perceba que o 1 é exemplo, você vai inserir a categoria que o usuário selecionou, use o string.Format ou concatene string.

Edit:
Respondendo a sua dúvida sobre reutilizar sempre a mesma coleção durante as etapas de vida do projeto, dê uma olhada no `static` e cuidado com o acesso concorrente e uso de memória do app.

Edit2: Digamos que `produtos` seja sua coleção de itens, segue um snipet usando sua classe  `Produtos`.

```
List<Produtos> produtos = new List<Produtos> {
        new Produtos { codCategoria = "1" },
        new Produtos { codCategoria = "2" },
        new Produtos { codCategoria = "3" },
        new Produtos { codCategoria = "4" },
        new Produtos { codCategoria = "5" },
        new Produtos { codCategoria = "6" },
        new Produtos { codCategoria = "7" },
    };

    var resultado = produtos.FindAll(p => p.codCategoria == "7");
```

`p` é cada produto dentro da coleção, depois você escreve a lógica para qual todo valor com resultado de expressão TRUE o produto será selecionado. O resultado é outra coleção apenas com os escolhidos. Lembre que a diferença entre o FindAll e o Where é o retorno, um retorna uma cópia dos elementos em outra coleção o outro apenas um enumerável.

No seu caso talvez o Where consuma menos memória, pois a coleção é estática você precisa apenas filtrar a mesma coleção para mostrar baseado no filtro do usuário.

Comment: é isto que eu desejo fazer, o problema é que todas as informações vem do mesmo webservice, estarei colocando um xml de exemplo da resposta do mesmo

Comment: Eu passo todas as informações da chamada para uma lista, gostaria de saber como reusar a lista para as próximas etapas, não sei se é possivel

Comment: Adicionei na resposta um recurso que pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: Eu ouvi dizer sobre usar o FindAll para encontrar todos os itens de tal categoria, você saberia me explicar ele? sobre o static, eu sempre uso nas minhas classes que usam 2 ou mais telas..

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo de FindAll genérico para você.

Comment: era realmente ele @Malkaviano, muito obrigado cara!